# Is it sin to call off a wedding?

Tags: nikah

I am a 25 years old girl. My marriage is about to happen in a month. It’s an arranged marriage. Everything was going well. But after marriage I want to live in a separate home with my husband. But my fiancee and his family are not accepting it. They want me to live with them. I tried to make them understand a lot. But they are not ready. Now I made up my mind to call this wedding off. I don’t want to get married and I told them that as well. Did I do wrong? Is it a sin to call off a wedding?

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model I strongly suggest you to take the [tour] and check our [help].

Comment: I've edit your tag: Please use meaningful and relevant tags. Maybe [Rejecting a marriage proposal](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/49775/marriage-proposal) is relevant.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a sin to call off a wedding. You don't have to marry a person that you don't want to marry. Arranged marriage has nothing to do with religion, it is just a tradition of many countries, it has been there for many years. Breaking a tradition is not a sin. But be respectful to your parents who arranged this wedding.